# Logback - how can you tell AsyncAppender's queue is full and starts dropping events?

Tags: java, logging, logback

Is there a way to know that logback is discarding logging events because the queue is full? Is it logged anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it.

The Appender silently discards event:

[AsyncAppenderBase.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/AsyncAppenderBase.java#L161)

```java
    @Override
    protected void append(E eventObject) {
        if (isQueueBelowDiscardingThreshold() && isDiscardable(eventObject)) {
            return;
        }
        preprocess(eventObject);
        put(eventObject);
    }
```

However, you can create your own appender by extending `AsyncAppenderBase`  or `AsyncAppender` and override `append` method with your custom logic.